# Sending Documents to SharePoint from external site using sharepoint send to connector / drop off library

Tags: drop-off-library, send-to-destination

I have two separate SharePoint Farms: "Source" and "Destination". Is it possible to send documents to a drop-off library in "Destination" from the "Source" site if both locations exist on separate farms? If so, I'm assuming that I will need to establish a trust between the farms. Anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the title of your Question you mention 'Send To', I'm assuming you mean this:

[image]

The Sharepoint Maven is a blog I follow since the author uses a lot of OOTB functionality instead of custom coding.  He does not recommend using the 'Send To' feature in Sharepoint.  Here is a [blog post](https://sharepointmaven.com/not-copy-files-sharepoint/) on this very subject.

Personally I tried to use it once, but a long time ago, so I don't remember the details.  See if someone else has some experience of using it, but based on the blog post it does not look promising.

The blogger also mentions that it can only send one document at a time!